# Escribir un txt con datos de diferentes listas y en cierto formato con Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy llevando a cabo un proyecto personal en python3 con spyder, que consiste en comenzar desde un archivo .nc o .hdf, extrayendo sus valores en diferentes listas en función de sus respectivos atributos, una vez que se han extraído los datos, generando un txt de salida en un formato específico, hasta ahora he logrado generar un archivo .txt, pero necesito generar un .txt con la cantidad de datos que tienen en los archivos antes mencionados, les muestro lo que tengo hasta ahora y dónde estoy atascado:

```
import netCDF4 as net
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nc = net.DataSet('path') # open file nc


dirPath = 'path_save' # path output .txt
out = open(dirPath,'w')  # txt en 'w' mode
u = nc.variables['u'][:] # access to variables with netcdf4
v = nc.variables['v ][:]

u1 = u.compressed() # extracting values to pass them to a list
u2 = u1.tolist() # Here I have a list with 3000 values

v1 = u.compressed()
v2 = v.tolist() # Here I have a list with 3000 values

out.write('Numbers \n')
out.writelines(' Numbers U   \n')
for i in u2[0:50]:
   out.writelines(str(i) + '\n')

out.writelines(' Numbers V   \n')   
for j in v2[0:50]:
   out.writelines(str(j) + '\n')


out.writelines(' ------   \n')
out.writelines(' ------   \n')
out.close()
```

Al ejecutar esto obtengo lo siguiente

out.txt con el siguiente formato:

```
 Numbers
 Numbers U
 0
 1
 -
 -
 50 
 Numbers V
 11
 12
 13
 -
 -
 60
 -----
 -----
```

En principio, he obtenido un txt con los primeros 50 datos y en el formato que he especificado, el problema es que quiero llenar el txt con los siguientes 50 valores de cada variable y con el formato creado, de modo que:

```
Numbers
Numbers U
0
1
-
-
50
Numbers V
11
12
13
-
-
60
-----
-----
Numbers
Numbers U
51
52
-
-
100
Numbers V
61
62
63
-
-
110
-----
-----
Numbers
Numbers U
101
102
-
-
150
Numbers V
111
112
113
-
-
160
-----
-----
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, 
saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes ver a continuación mi propuesta al problema del formateo específico que planteas. Te copio el código tal y como lo acabo de probar con python 3.8.

### Notas:

- No copio la parte relacionada con netCDF4 ya que dices que te funciona y yo no lo tengo instalado
- Incluye constantes para aumentar la legibilidad, y por si necesitas adaptarlo. Por ejemplo cambiando el NUMERO_DE_BLOQUES
- El programa presupone que NUMERO_DE_VALORES es divisible por LONGITUD_DE_BLOQUES.

### Comentarios de la solución:

- Simplemente realiza un bucle con el número de bloques a escribir
- Dentro de cada bloque usa la función 'join', que permite unir los 50 elementos de cada bloque, usando como delimitador el salto de línea ('\n')
- Se usan rebanadas('slicing'): u2[i * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE: (i + 1) * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE]) para obtener de la lista u2 los 50 elementos de cada bloque.
- Esto se realiza tanto para la lista u2 como para la v2.
- Y finalmente se unen los fragmentos anteriores

```
# Cadenas fijas
CABECERA = 'Numbers \n'
CABECERA_U = 'Numbers U   \n'
CABECERA_V = 'Numbers V   \n'
PIE = '------   \n'

# Constant numbers
NUMERO_DE_VALORES = 3000  # Nº total de valores en cada lista
LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE = 50  # Nº de valores de cada lista a escribir en cada bloque
NUMERO_DE_BLOQUES = int(NUMERO_DE_VALORES / LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE)

# Relleno las listas con valores para probar. Esta parte debes de cambiarla por tu código
u2 = list(range(0, NUMERO_DE_VALORES))
v2 = list(range(11, NUMERO_DE_VALORES + 11))

# Formateo de los resultados
total = ""
for i in range(0, NUMERO_DE_BLOQUES):
    u_block = CABECERA_U + '\n'.join(str(x) for x in u2[i * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE: (i + 1) * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE]) + '\n'
    v_block = CABECERA_V + '\n'.join(str(x) for x in v2[i * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE: (i + 1) * LONGITUD_DEL_BLOQUE]) + '\n'
    block = CABECERA + u_block + v_block + 2 * PIE
    total += block

# Escritura en el fichero
dirPath = 'path_save'  # path output .txt
out = open(dirPath, 'w')  # txt en 'w' mode
out.write(total)
out.close()
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección Angel, lo he probado con listas  de miles de elementos y funciona perfecto y con esto puedo añadir el formato que necesite, gracias por tu rápida respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Una pregunta para terminar de entender el output de un txt, en caso de querer el resultado por columnas, tendría que modificar solo la parte de la  escritura o dentro del bucle también? ?

Comment: Te recomiendo algunas alternativas:  [Create nice column output in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989334/create-nice-column-output-in-python)    También puedes probar a  usar [ColumnPrinter](https://books.google.es/books?id=ocmqBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=python+ColumnPrinter&source=bl&ots=ZDkixXiF6A&sig=ACfU3U3y7pt452XkWjNDkbAMXwk4Hh_dWA&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim2qXs1MnnAhWEyIUKHSqjAZgQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=python%20ColumnPrinter&f=false)